# Method for having 2 balls drawn with replacement

Tags: probability, statistics

(2 points) An urn contains 3 balls number 1 to 3. Two balls are drawn with replacement. Let X be the value of larger of the two numbers drawn. P(X=2)?

**I do not know how to begin this, I'm really thrown off with "let X be value larger than 2 numbers drawn". Would that be like drawing a ball with 1 and a ball with 3 or a ball with 1 and a ball with a 2?**

What steps would I need to do in order to obtain the solution of: P(x=2)=?

Comment: I suspect it means the larger of the values chosen.  Thus if you choose any of $(1,2),(2,1),(2,2)$ the larger of the values chosen is $2$.

Comment: I agree that it is a weird formulation. If this is an exam question, you might want to suggest to be more clear on written exams.

Comment: An equivalent formulation is let $X,Y$ be i.i.d. random variables uniform on $\{1,2,3\}$. Define, $Z=\max\{X,Y\}$, what is $\mathbb{P}(Z=2)$

Answer (score 1):

$S={(1,1),(1,2), (1,3)
      (2,1), (2,2), (2,3),
      (3,1), (3,2), (3,3)}$

Therefore the sample space contains 9 items/events.

We assume that each combinations has an equal chance of being chosen, so each combination has a $1/9$ chance of being chosen.

$Pr(X=2)=Pr((1,2), (2,1) or (2,2))=1/9+1/9+1/9=3/9=1/3$

Comment: Hi! Thank you for answering! I am wondering how you got 3/9

Comment: @GillDave  Of the nine possible outcomes in the sample space, three have largest element $2$.  They are $(1, 2)$, $(2, 1)$, and $(2, 2)$.

Comment: @GillDave I updated the answer to show more steps

Answer (score 0):

Oh, bother!  Amanda R just pointed out the balls are numbered 1 to 3, not 0 to 2!  The computation is basically the same.

The largest of the two numbers will be 2 for (1, 2), (2 ,1), or (2, 2). That is three out of the total 3*3= 16 possible results drawing two balls.  P(2)= 3/9.

(Although you didn't ask, 1 is the "larger" only for (1,1).  The probability is P(1)= 1/9.
  1 is the larger only for (1, 1). The probability is P(1)= 1/9.

Three is larger for (1, 3), (2, 3), (3, 1), (3, 2) and (3, 3).  The probability P(3)= 5/9.

Of course, 3/9+ 1/9+ 5/9= 9/9= 1.)

Thanks Amanda R!

Comment: OP stated that there are 3 balls numbered 1-3

Answer (score 0):

Let $X_1,X_2$ be your draws. Then $X_1,X_2$ are i.i.d. uniform on $\{1,2,3\}$. Now you want to compute $\mathbb{P}(Z=2)$ where $Z=\max \{X_1,X_2\}$.

Generally, you have $\mathbb{P}(Z\leq t) =\mathbb{P}(X_1\leq t,X_2\leq t)=\mathbb{P}(X_1\leq t)\mathbb{P}(X_2\leq t)  $. Thereofore,
\begin{align}
\mathbb{P}(Z=2) &= \mathbb{P}(Z\leq 2)- \mathbb{P}(Z\leq 1)\\
&=\frac{2}{3} \cdot\frac{2}{3}   - \frac{1}{3} \cdot \frac{1}{3} \\
&= 1/3
\end{align}